# Ordenar dataFrame con sort_values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ordenamiento

Cuando ordeno mi dataFrame con sort_values, en vez de ordenarme se me transforman los datos de la columna la cual quiero ordenar por [-1], sabéis por que puede estar pasando?? Gracias!!
es decir: me gustaría ordenar el resto de datos según mi columna patientId que es algo asi:

[image: la primera imagen es como lo tengo]
[image: esta imagen es lo que me aparece]

y lo que quiero es que ordene de menor a mayor a los pacientes y ademas ponga juntas las columnas el cual se repite el paciente

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y coloca un [repro] de tu código.

Comment: Quizá tengas casos donde patientid es -1

Comment: Lo que comenta Dante S es la explicación más plausible a lo que planteas, `sort_values` no va a modificar el contenido de la columna en ningun caso, a no ser que estés haciendo otras operaciones por medio. En cualquier caso, sin un ejemplo mínimo verificable o al menos el código concreto que estás usando es muy difícil que alguien te pueda ayudar, si sigues con el problema edita la pregunta agregando más información.